# auto update data from a column in another workbook to a column based on sheet name

Tags: excel, vba

I have 2 workbooks named:

1. Staff workbook contains such columns: Staff ID and Department...
2. Salary workbook: has several sheet and each sheet is named based on a particular Department's name. In each sheet contains such column: Staff ID.

My question is that: is there anyway to auto update all values from Staff ID column in 1st workbook to the Staff ID column in 2nd workbook based on the sheet name in the 2nd workbook?

Example: When I open Salary workbook, in Accounting sheet, it will auto get all staff ids from Accounting Department in the Staff workbook.

I try to google all day but could not find such solution. Any help or hint would greatly appreciated.

Comment: Yes, there is a way.

Answer (score 0):

You can put this on each workbook

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()
    *code to update StaffID*
End Sub
```

This will trigger the code whenever that Worksheet is activated

Comment: could you please be more specific how do achieve this? Because I am new to vba, please help if you could. thanks

Comment: Right click on worksheet tab -> View Code.  This will get you to visual basic editor. Copy the above code, and put in your code for updating StaffID. Then whenever you activate that worksheet, it will update StaffID.